# How can I partition so that most of my data lives on the SSD, and only when I run out of space do I go to the HDD?

Tags: fedora, partition

I previously had an Ubuntu/Windows dual boot, with `/` in the SSD and `/home` in the HDD.

I decided to switch out Ubuntu for Fedora, and I made the mistake of not partitioning properly. It looks like `/home` is now in the SSD and my previous `/home` (and all the real data) is just in "Other Locations" (so basically a different partition).

Either way, what I would like to do now is the following:

- SSD:

  - Should contain `/` (and everything needed to boot).
  - Should also contain `/home`. Or at least as much as possible.
- HDD:

  - Should contain the Windows partition (already taken care of).
  - Should contain the `/home` overflow from SSD. This should only get populated if the SSD runs out of space, at least ideally.
  - The swap partition for fedora.

Is this possible? I don't see why it wouldn't be, but I'm not an expert by any means.
Also, I don't mind re-installing Fedora entirely and I actually prefer it since it'll probably be easier to partition and I haven't set up my settings/preferences in the latest install yet anyway.

Here's what I get when I run `lsblk`:

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2            8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3            8:3    0 110.6G  0 part 
  ├─fedora-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─fedora-swap 253:1    0  11.2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─fedora-home 253:2    0  49.4G  0 lvm  /home
sdb               8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1            8:17   0   9.5G  0 part 
├─sdb2            8:18   0     1T  0 part /run/media/username/76e469ef-7da2-4cd3-97f8-bdb1bd3b2a7e
├─sdb3            8:19   0   450M  0 part 
├─sdb4            8:20   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdb5            8:21   0    16M  0 part 
└─sdb6            8:22   0 761.5G  0 part /run/media/username/C6FA5190FA517E1D
sdc               8:32   1   3.8G  0 disk 
├─sdc1            8:33   1   1.5G  0 part /run/media/username/Fedora-WS-Live-27-1-6
├─sdc2            8:34   1   8.8M  0 part 
└─sdc3            8:35   1  18.6M  0 part 
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

- sda is the SSD.
- sdb is the HDD.
- sdb1, sdb3, sdb4, sdb5, sdb6 are all Windows partitions. Don't ask me why there are so many. Not sure if I did it or if Windows itself does it that way.
- sdb2 contains my previous `/home` from when I had Ubuntu.
- sdc is just the USB which has the Fedora installer.

At the end of the day, I would like to make sdb2 part of `/home` as well. And get the swap partition out of the SSD to avoid the wear and tear.

Furthermore, I don't mind manually copying files from sdb6 (old ubuntu `/home`), if necessary, by the way. There aren't that many files.

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to use LVM to create a linear array with PVs on the SSD and HDD.

Comment: I opted to not have the HDD as part of `/home`, but mount it on `/media/shared` and move `~/Music`, `~/Videos` and `/~Pictures` (which take up most of my data) over to it, then add symlinks to them in my `/home` directory. This works quite well, since none of those need rapid read speeds, while most other data that needs to be more readily accessible can be on the SSD.